# Spring: automatic rollback on checked exceptions

Tags: java, spring, transactional

One way to configure Spring to rollback on a non `RuntimeExceptions` is using `@Transactional(rollbackFor=...)` annotation on the service classes. The problem with this approach is that we need to define (rollbackFor=...) for almost all the service classes which seems really redundant.

---

My question: Is there any way to configure a default behaviour for Spring transaction manager to rollback on a non `RuntimeException` whenever it happens without declaring it on every `@Transactional` annotation. Something like using `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)` annotation on an exception class in EJB.

Comment: Check this "Rolling Back" section: http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/declarative-transaction-management.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do it for application level with @Transactional , but you can :

**variant 1 :** extend @Transactional annotation and put it as default value for rollbackfor. But set rollbackFor unchecked exceptions only that you need .With this you  can control rollbacks only for case that you sure , and avoid copy past of @Transactional(rollbackFor =MyCheckedException.class)

Like:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(rollbackFor=MyCheckedException.class)
public @interface TransactionalWithRollback {
}
```

And use this annotation instead of standard  @Transactional.

**variant 2 :** you can create extension from [AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.html) and override  method determineTransactionAttribute:

```
protected TransactionAttribute  determineTransactionAttribute(AnnotatedElement ae)
//Determine the transaction attribute for the given method or class.
```

TransactionAttribute see [TransactionAttribute api](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttribute.html) , there is a method

> boolean    rollbackOn(Throwable ex) Should we roll back on the given exception?

```
protected TransactionAttribute determineTransactionAttribute(
    AnnotatedElement ae) {
    return new DelegatingTransactionAttribute(target) {
        @Override
        public boolean rollbackOn(Throwable ex) {
           return (check is exception type as you need for rollback );
       }
};
```

}

Second approach is not so good as first as you do it really global for transaction manager. Better use custom annotation as you can control it any apply only for methods/classes where you really need it. But if you need it in any case use second variant , it will be your default transnational behavior.

Comment: Thank you, extending @Transactional annotation is a great idea.

Comment: @xyz I have used the second variant over years, but with spring boot 2.1 / spring 5.1 it stops working. There is no error, but the behavior of `@Transactional` is now the usual one and not the wanted one. – t777 7 mins ago

Comment: @xyz I'm considering adopting your second variant because it would be easier and other programmers working with the code won't have to think about it. But I don't want to make any mistakes. - why wouldn't it be "so good" to do it globally as mentioned in your second variant?
Is there a case where it makes sense to not rollback for a checked exception? I'm honestly curious.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I must say that your second variant can break noRollbackFor option of annotation @Transactional, so you should be careful

Answer (score 11):

This config solves it:

```
@Configuration
public class MyProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration extends ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
    public TransactionAttributeSource transactionAttributeSource() {
        return new AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource() {

            @Nullable
            protected TransactionAttribute determineTransactionAttribute(AnnotatedElement element) {
                TransactionAttribute ta = super.determineTransactionAttribute(element);
                if (ta == null) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    return new DelegatingTransactionAttribute(ta) {
                        @Override
                        public boolean rollbackOn(Throwable ex) {
                            return super.rollbackOn(ex) || ex instanceof Exception;
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Best solution for changing things globally, thanks!

Comment: @Nullable is unknown annotation in my project - what spring version is it? In addition, adding this configuration class to my project prevents the service from starting up. It fails to instantiate BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor  due to a NPE. Any idea why this may happen?!

Comment: Spring version is 5.
Look at the check the stack trace to see where the NPE comes from.

Comment: You can simplify "return super.rollbackOn(ex) || ex instanceof Exception" with "return true" because the super call already returns true for Error, so if you add Exception it covers all the Throwable subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar approach as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54348838/3552141), i.e. changing the default globally, but with as minimal change to Spring's config as possible, and still leaving the possibility to customize rollback rules per method as usual (with `rollbackFor`, `noRollbackFor` etc.).

This is achieved by simply adding a default RollbackRule for `Exception.class`. Since the rules have precedence according to the exception class hierarchy (the rule for the most specific exception class applicable wins), the new rule has basically lowest precendence, if no other rules are defined on the annotation.

```java
@Configuration
public class MyTransactionManagementConfiguration {
  /**
   * Note: This custom config does NOT recognize {@code javax.transaction.Transactional} annotations in contrast to
   * the original Spring behaviour. Check the original {@code AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource} source code for an idea how to add that.
   *
   * @see AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource(boolean)
   */
  @Bean
  @Primary
  @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
  public TransactionAttributeSource transactionAttributeSourceWithDefaultRollBackForAllExceptions() {
    return new AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource(
        new SpringTransactionAnnotationParser() {
          
          @Override
          protected TransactionAttribute parseTransactionAnnotation(AnnotationAttributes attributes) {
            RuleBasedTransactionAttribute rbta = (RuleBasedTransactionAttribute) super.parseTransactionAnnotation(attributes);
            List<RollbackRuleAttribute> rules = new ArrayList<>(rbta.getRollbackRules());
            rules.add(new RollbackRuleAttribute(Exception.class));
            rbta.setRollbackRules(rules);
            return rbta;
          }

        }
    );
  }
}
```