# Rollback on every exception with @Transaction and spring boot 2.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactional

Using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3702433/1869090) my application rolls back on every exception.

But starting with spring boot 2.1 the rollback is just done for `RuntimeException`s.

I cannot see any regarding change in the change logs of spring boot.

Any ideas?

Comment: The linked solution is for a very old Spring version (from 9 years ago at least). I recommend to see this question to get a newer solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898884/spring-automatic-rollback-on-checked-exceptions

Comment: @Dherik Thanks for the link. It is similar to my solution, but it is not working with spring boot 2.1 / spring 5.1. There is no error, but the behavior of `@Transactional` is now the usual one and not the wanted one