# JPA/Hibernate rolling back list of children is not working

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, db2

I'm using a DB2 Database and JPA/Hibernate with Java Springboot, but rolling back a transaction when using JPA's .save() method is not working. My main entity is not saved because it is used/blocked by another program, but its children are saved. But I need all or nothing!

For example:
I have two entities in my project A and B. A has a List of Bs:

```java
@Entity
@Data // Lombok
public class A {
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<B> bs;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class B {
  // some fields.
}
```

When I add a B to the list in A and save it, it should add a row in the db-table of B. This is working fine.
But if there is an error with A, i.e. it is blocked by another program, it saves the changed Bs too but it should not. I already tried to use @Transactional but it doesn't change anything. Saving A returns an exception but the list of Bs is saved although it should rollback to in my understanding :/

```java
try {
  A savedA = aRepository.save(a);
  return savedA;
} catch (DataAccessException e) {
  throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Is already used by another program.", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you configured auto-commit on your data source? This is a spring question related to transactions/datasources so you should probably change the labels/tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that spring's default transactional strategy is on  unchecked exceptions [1.4.3. Rolling Back a Declarative Transaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back)

> In its default configuration, the Spring Framework’s transaction infrastructure code marks a transaction for rollback only in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions. That is, when the thrown exception is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException. ( Error instances also, by default, result in a rollback). Checked exceptions that are thrown from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the default configuration.

That means sub exception which is subclass of java.lang.RuntimeException or Error it will roll back.
But sub exception which is subclass of java.lang.Exception like IOException, TimeoutException it will not rollback.

I think your Exception is TimeoutException so it will not rollback.
So may be your problem now is how to rollback on checked exception,you can check this [Spring: automatic rollback on checked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898884/spring-automatic-rollback-on-checked-exceptions/44899098)